# Take Elements of a List

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to delete the first element of a list of a list in Mathematica. For example I have:

```
x= {{{1,2},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},{{10,11},{13,14,15},{16,17,18}}}
```

I want the answer like this:

> {{{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},{{13,14,15},{16,17,18}}}

How can I do that??

Thanks

Comment: If anyone disagrees with closing, please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to evaluate

```
Map[Rest, x, 1]
```

which returns

> ```
> {{{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}}
> ```

Similarly,

```
Drop[x, None, 1]
```

returns the same output.

---

**edit**: The second way is probably the faster of the two

Answer (score 6):

```
x[[All, 2 ;;]] (* or x[[;; , 2 ;;]] *)
```

> {{{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}}

Also:

```
☺ = {##2} & @@@ # &;
☺ @ x
> {{{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Cases[x, {{__}, {a__}, {b__}} :> {{a}, {b}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answers you can use the function `Delete`

```
Delete[{{{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{10, 11}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 
    17, 18}}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}]
```

The resulting

> {{{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
x = {{{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{10, 11}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}};

y = x;
y[[All, 1]] = Nothing;
(*or*)
y2 = Drop[x, 0, 1];

y === y2
```

> ```
> True
> ```