# Is Map[Rest,#]& (counterintuitively) better than Drop[#,None,1]?

Tags: list-manipulation

This question is motivated by considering different alternative answers to [*this*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161723/take-elements-of-a-list) question.

More specifically, *this* question intends to investigate what appears to be an unexpected outcome (at least, unexpected by *me*).

This unexpected outcome has to do with the relative *effectiveness* of using two built-in symbols/functions to answer the linked question, namely using a combination of `Map` and `Rest` against using just `Drop`.

The intuition, from working knowledge of the language, was that using `Map` would be *in general* less efficient than using `Drop`. This intuition was verified by applying the relevant approaches to the question's input.

I will replicate the input from that question and the two proposed approaches for the purpose of providing this question with an appropriate context

```
x = {{{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{10, 11}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}}};

{tMap,resMap} = Map[Rest, x] // RepeatedTiming;

{tDrop, resDrop} = Drop[x, None, 1] // RepeatedTiming;

tMap / tDrop
```

returns `3.`, as expected.

Going a step further, to confirm the intuition, I sought to replicate the results. The test setup I used, is provided in the end of this question.

The gist of it was to generate a number of use-case *similar* to the input and use several proposed approaches in order to gauge which performed best.

An assumption in the test set up was that the source of variance in the input is mostly due to the dimension in level 1. Longer lists in level 1 would (supposedly) imply more applications of `Rest` and hence more time. Similar considerations were related to the application of `Drop` (I assumed, `Drop` works in an analogous fashion).

To make a long story short, it turns out that my intuition was **wrong**.

[image]

The collection of graphs above summarizes the results of a single run of testing 8 proposed solutions on 640 discrete use cases. As anyone can see in the highlighted bar-charts, `Drop` is the *third* best performing solution in  5.2% of the test cases while `Map` is the *first* best performing solution in 5.8% of the use cases.

These ranking change between different runs of the tests but they seem to be consistent in that `Map` out-performs `Drop` (another feature seems to be that `Part` appears to be a better choice, in general).

In light of these findings and conditional upon the nature of the task at hand (dropping the first entry in a list of lists) ***is it safe to assume that using `Map` is a better choice than using `Drop` most of the time (and using `Part` is probably the best choice in general) ?***

---

code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/uNUQbyYZ)

**edit**: updated graphs/changed implementation of a function as indicated in the comments;

[image]

**edit #2**: updated graphs after correction suggested by @Coolwater (thank you)

[image]

***note***: this correction answers the question in the negative: `Map` is **not** counterintuitively faster than `Drop`; in fact, changing the code as suggested verifies initial intuition; additionally, it seems that `Part` is indeed a *good* choice (along with using `Drop` as *originally* suggested by @Coolwater).

Comment: I haven't looked carefully at your code, but is it possible that sometimes the lists that you are generating are packed and sometimes they're not? That might make a difference.

Comment: no, at least, not explicitly or intentionally; the testing is done on random integer lists with dimensions from `Outer[List,{2, 10, 100, 500, 1000},{3, 5, 7, 9},{3, 5, 7, 9},1]`

Comment: I don't think kglr's `Function` variant is fairly tested: you're wrapping the assignment of the function to the symbol inside a `Module` and doing repeated timing on the whole thing instead of just `\[HappySmiley]@x // RepeatedTiming`. It's a bit tedious to make out the details of your test code to comment on its validity, but are you only working on packed arrays? What if there's a ragged array? Does it matter if sublists are packed? Lot's of hard-to-compare edge cases. The relative amount of times one approach or another came first doesn't tell me much. What about their actual run times?

Comment: 1. changed the implementation as suggested; 2. with all due respect I'd consider my code fairly straightforward; I'd happily accept pointers 3. I'm not using packed arrays explicitly 4. ragged arrays would make things worse for all approaches; they were not in the context of the question that motivated the testing; 5. how are integer lists of varying length "edge-cases" 6. absolute times are easily obtained from my code; why are ranks not relevant for comparisons of relative performance (what I'm trying to do)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` is not fast. The `Map`-function is defined as the 3rd one, and the 3rd fastest function is defined as the first one. Hence you report `Map` as fastest. You need to replace

```
Ordering[map, len, Last[#1] < Last[#2] &]
```

by

```
Ordering[Ordering[map, len, Last[#1] < Last[#2] &]]
```